# Why does Array.map allow me to pass members which are not of the generic type

Tags: typescript

Why is that when using `Array.map<T>` I am allowed to map properties which do not exist on `T`?

I am using `strict: true` in my `tsconfig.json`

```
interface MappedItem {
    foo: number;
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];

// I would expect this to error, but it does not
arr.map<MappedItem>(n => ({ foo: n, bar: n }));

arr.map(n => {
    // This errors as expected
    // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bar' does not exist in type 'MappedItem'
    const item: MappedItem = { foo: n, bar: n };

    return item;
});
```

Comment: Seems you found a bug

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien not necessarily a but just the way it works, the function is typed without regard to the expected return type.. I am sure I have answerd this before but can't fin it.. `arr.map((n): MappedItem => ({ foo: n, bar: n }));` should yield excess property check errors

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I think it asserts the type of the return, However, I think even that it should not work with ```{ foo: n, bar: n } as MappedItem```, but it does. Do you know why?

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien The error is only due to excess property, an assertion will silence the errors, assertions generally make compatibility rules more relaxed

Comment: That makes some sense to me, just feeling weird - likes they let the code asserts something it is sure to be wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
arr.map<MappedItem>(n => ({ foo: n, bar: n }));
```

the type variable is used to denote what is being returned, in this case `MappedItem[]`.

**When checking if an object is of a certain type, the compiler only checks that at least the properties (etc.) required are present and match the types required.*

Clearly, the objects you return satisfy the requirement `MappedItem` dictates: have a property `foo` of type `number`. So when it looks like a `MappedItem`, it is a `MappedItem` (this is called duck typing).

But when you use

```
const item: MappedItem = { foo: n, bar: n };
```

then the case is different, because **Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments*, because *TypeScript takes the stance that there’s probably a bug in this code*.

So the error you see is a special case, a safety measure.

You can get around it with a type assertion, like:

```
const item: MappedItem = { foo: n, bar: n } as MappedItem;
```

You read about more about it in the *[handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

Comment: Nice answer, but where did you find the quote :D @sloth

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien In the handbook I linked at the end of my answer. I don't think typescript has currently an up-to-date specification.

Comment: Yeah, I found the second one but not the first